# X11 Forwarding: SDL Error: Couldn't find matching render driver

Tags: opengl, cygwin, sdl, x11-forwarding

Here's the situation:

I am trying to do X11 Forwarding from a Linux server to a windows client (running cygwin). I've been playing around with SDL tutorials (these specifically: http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php). I've been downloading, compiling, and running the examples and this had been working on the first couple, so I jumped to 8 and when I try to run the program I get a "SDL Error: Couldn't find matching render driver" error. When I am locally on the Linux server, everything works fine (and I have no problem doing the who X11 forwarding to my linux workstation).

My cygwin packages installed:
xorg-server
xinit
mesa
openssh

I open cygwin, run startxwin, and then ssh into the server with the -XY flags, and the try to run the compiled example.

From my understanding of X11 Forwarding, the linux server should be sending opengl rendering instructions back to my local machine to process. So the SDL Error should be because my local machine can't find a renderer -- which I thought would be provided by mesa.